# What Is Wrong With Javascript Replace Method?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a problem with REPLACE method for strings .
I have a string witch contains 1 or 2 or ... same string and I want to replace all of them to one thing but replace method doesn't work , follow this :

```
var a = "hihi";
b = a.replace("hi","hello");
alert(b);
```

It should alert hellohello but it alerts hellohi .

Please help . Thanks .

Comment: Pease do not minus this question, while question asker could have written it better it's a legitimate question, since MDN documentation doesn't match behavior in Chrome (and maybe other browsers)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression with the global `g` set to replace all occurrences in the string.

```
var string = 'hihi';
var result = string.replace(/hi/g, 'hello');
alert(result); // 'hellohello'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what if hi is in a variable ?